# Android opens application without enough permission

Tags: android, permissions

I am starting to develop in Android and I am trying to understand Permissions, however the apps I made are not working and the "Dangerous" app is being opened even if the opener app doesn't have the required permissions to open it.

Dangerous manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.second_dangerousapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
     android:name="com.dangerous_app.permission.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"
    android:label="@string/label_dangerousActivity"
    android:description="@string/description_dangerousActivity"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.APP_INFO" >
</permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.second_dangerousapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The app itself is a simple textview with text.

Then the opener app
Permissions manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.second_permissions"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.second_permissions.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the code of the main activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOpen);
    btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent open = new    Intent("android.intent.action.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY");
            startActivity(open);
        }
    });
}
```

What I am doing wrong. Cause right now the permission app shouldn't be able to open the dangerous app as it doesn't have the required permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cause right now the permission app shouldn't be able to open the dangerous app as it doesn't have the required permission.

You are not defending anything in your app with the custom permission. Just having a `<permission>` element does nothing, other than define the permission. You *also* need to *apply* the permission somewhere, such as via an `android:permission` attribute on your `<activity>`.

You may also want to read [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/02/12/vulnerabilities-custom-permissions.html) about some unexpected behavior with respect to custom permissions.

Comment: Can you put an example. I cant find any working example.

Comment: Found the answer.

`android:permission="com.dangerous_app.permission.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"`